# iOS swift 3 coding tableview edit button using UIButton instead of UIBarButton

Tags: ios, swift3

I wrote the following code. I'm trying to make it so that it functions like act like `UIBarButtonItem` edit item function, but using a `UIButton` instead because I have a custom navigation bar, but I'm having several compiling errors. The function is supposed to allow editing when the button is pressed and finish editing when pressed again.

```
@IBAction func edit(sender: UIButton){
    if [tableView.isEditing] == YES {
        [self.tableView .setEditing(false, animated: false)]
    }
    else{
        [self.tableView .setEditing(true, animated: true)]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up Swift and Objective-C code, should look something like this

```
@IBAction func edit(sender: UIButton) {
    if tableView.isEditing {
        tableView.setEditing(false, animated: false)
    } else{
        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    }
}
```